# How to detect finger drawing location on a DialogFragment

Tags: android, touch-event, dialogfragment

I have been developing a function that allows users to draw a pattern (similar to the pattern unlock feature that comes with Android).  I successfully implemented this function in an Activity using onTouchEvent():

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        // finish
    }
    if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
        // get drawing location
        int x = (int) event.getX();
        int y = (int) event.getY();

        ......
    }

    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Now, I hope to do the same thing using a DialogFragment.  However, a DialogFragment does not have a onTouchEvent Listener.  Therefore, I cannot use the code implemented in an Activity.

Any ideas will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Create a View subclass, overriding the `onTouchEvent()` method, and set that as the Dialog's content View.

Comment: Thank you.  I used your approach.  However, there is only a onTouch() method to override (not onTouchEvent()).  This onTouch() method can only detect MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN and never hit MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE.  Very weird.  Please help.

Comment: If your method is `onTouch()`, then I don't believe you've (strictly, at least) subclassed View. It sounds like you've set an `OnTouchListener` for it, which should work, too, but you've got to return the correct value in the `onTouch()` method. Short comment answer: `return true;`, but you'll need to investigate touch event handling for the complete, proper way to do it.